# Передача Socket по ссылке

Tags: java, сервер

При передаче сокета в функцию, мне нужно его в этой фукнции приравнять - null; 
Пример:

```
   Socket socket;
       Handler(Socket socket) // конструктор некого класса
     {
 this.socket = socket;
    Check(this.socket)
}
public void Check(Socket socket)
{
   socket = null;
}
// но socket по-прежнему != null;
```

Почему так? И как передать его так, чтобы я смог его переприравнивать, например не к null, а к другому сокету

///////////////////////////////////////////

```
    public class item { //класс для примера, что принимает два сокета

           Socket socket;
           Socket socket_next;

       public item(Socket socket, Socket socket_next) {

               this.socket = socket;
               this.socket_next = socket_next;
             }
       }


     public class Handler{
       Socket socket;
         Handler(Socket socket) throws IOException // конструктор
 {
      this.socket = socket;
      item I = new item(this.socket, null);   
      NULL(I);


  } 

       public void NULL(item I)
       {
        I.socket = null;
        }
}
```

Comment: Должно быть так: `this.socket = null;` . Добавьте полный класс этого кода, чтоб можно было воспроизвести.

Comment: @MyFylypenko
Боюсь не выйдет. Т.к я пишу многопоточный сервер, и обнуление\переприравнивание происходит в совершенно другом потоке. Но:

Answer (score 2):

В Java **все** параметры передаются **по значению**.

Обнуление объекта, переданного в метод, не повлечет за собой обнуление этого объекта извне, так как в метод передается **копия** ссылки.

---

**UPD**:

Изменение *поля* класса:

```
class StringWrapper {
    private String mStr;

    public String getStr() {
        return mStr;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        mStr = str;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringWrapper stringWrapper = new StringWrapper();
        stringWrapper.setStr("Foo");
        System.out.println(stringWrapper.getStr());
        bar(stringWrapper);
        System.out.println(stringWrapper.getStr());

    }

    private static void bar(StringWrapper stringWrapper) {
        stringWrapper.setStr(null);
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
Foo
null
```

Comment: Я пытался обернуть socket  в класс, но т.е он все-равно не обнулялся

Comment: @кириллмоисеенков, А вот в этом случае, обнуление должно происходить. Покажите код.

Comment: добавил. В оригинальном коде этот самый класс с сокетами путешествует в самописную DataBase , где и должен обнуляться

Comment: @кириллмоисеенков, Покажите минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Пока в коде из вопроса каша.

Comment: в чем я тут ошибся? (привел пример)

Comment: @ post_zeew я , вроде, разобрался, спасибо вам!

Comment: @кириллмоисеенков, В примере поле `socket` класса `item` должно обнуляться.